# Find all possible Laurent expansions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

What does this mean? I have a question in my book that says find all possible Laurent expansions of $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2-1)(z-4)}$ centered at $z=0$. I was able to break this down to a certain point, but I guess I'm confused on what it means by all possible expansions.

Here is what I have so far:

$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2-1)(z-4)} = \frac{1}{10} \frac{1}{z+1} - \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{15} \frac{1}{z-4}$. Do I have to consider cases such as $|z| < 1$, $1<|z|<4$, and $4<|z|$. Or am I not understanding what the question is asking me?

For $|z|<1$ I think this is right so far, but I was able to get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{6} + \frac{(-1)^n}{10} - \frac{1}{15(4)^{n+1}})z^n$. Are the other regions I have listed all that I have left? Or are there more I'm missing out on, and is what I've done so far correct?

Comment: The poles are at $1,-1$ and $4$. you have to expand it in powers of $z-1$ around $1$, etc.

Comment: Sorry, the question specified centered at $z=0$ and I have it fixed now.

Comment: I think you have a typo, but yes—there will be three different Laurent expansions around $0$: one converging in the disk $|z|<1$, one converging in the annulus $1<|z|<4$, and one converging in the disk-exterior $|z|>4$. Your first answer looks right to me!

Comment: You’re totally right, there is a typo I’ll fix that now thank you!

Comment: Is the one that I've done correct for the region I defined? Or is that correct for the region $1<|z|<4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill in the details. The idea is $f(z)=\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{z+1}-\frac16\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{15}\frac{1}{z-4}$, so in some shape or form you always want you use the geometric series formula,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$
for $|z|<1$, but with some algebraic manipulation.

About $z=0$, the nearest singularity is at $z=1$ and $z=-1$. Starting with $|z|<1$, write
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{1-(-z)}+\frac16\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{15}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{4}}.
$$
All geometric series are valid since $|z|<1$ so $|\frac{z}{4}|<1$.

Then in the region $1<|z|<4$, observe that if $w=\frac{1}{z}$, then $\frac14<|w|<1$ so write
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{z})}-\frac16\cdot\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}-\frac{1}{15}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{4}}.
$$
See if you can handle the final case. The purpose of the exercise is to think of the Laurent series in this way.

Comment: I was able to get the final case down, however, on this case here, with what you've done I just simply find treat this as individual geometric series and then combine them all at the end?

Comment: Also, for the region $1<|z|<4$ I got $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{10(z^{n+1})} - \frac{1}{6(z^n)} - \frac{z^n}{15(4^{n+1})}$ is this correct?

Comment: I'm not going to calculate them all, just show you the idea.

Comment: Okay, I understand that, my question is then do I individually calculate the geometric series and then combine them all into one series at the end per case

Comment: You should be able to.

Comment: Thank you I think I got it!